# Converting long, lat to tile of NASA GIBS - WGS 84 / Lat-lon / Geographic (EPSG:4326)?

Tags: coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, wgs84, wmts, nasa

I'm following [GIBS API for Developers](https://wiki.earthdata.nasa.gov/display/GIBS/GIBS+API+for+Developers) and I need to convert `long, lat` of POI to `col` and `row` of tile for given `zoom`. For example to get right tile in endpoint like:

`https://gibs.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts/epsg4326/best/MODIS_Terra_CorrectedReflectance_TrueColor/default/{date}/250m/{zoom}/{row}/{col}.jpg`

I'm using python and already tried few libs:

- https://github.com/geometalab/pyGeoTile
- https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj
- https://gist.github.com/tucotuco/1193577

But didn't get right `row, col` values. As I see the main problem that all of them are basing on idea that lat map direct to y and you should just divide to 180˚ and mult to 2^zoom. But actually it doesn't work and it is very easy to check.

[New Zealand location is about 41° 174°](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Zealand). And for `zoom = 3` you should calc row that way:

```
row = int((90˚ + 41˚) / 180˚ * 2 ^ 3) ≈ int(5,8222) = 5 
col = int((180˚ + 174˚) / 180˚ * 2 ^ 3) ≈ int(15.73333) = 15
```

So here you should see New Zealand:

https://gibs.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts/epsg4326/best/MODIS_Terra_CorrectedReflectance_TrueColor/default/2016-09-03/250m/3/5/15.jpg

but actually we are out of tiles. Image:

[image]

Response:

```
<ExceptionReport xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/ows/1.1.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd" version="1.1.0" xml:lang="en">
  <Exception exceptionCode="TileOutOfRange" locator="TILECOL">
    <ExceptionText>TILECOL is out of range, maximum value is 9</ExceptionText>
  </Exception>
  <Exception exceptionCode="TileOutOfRange" locator="TILEROW">
    <ExceptionText>TILEROW is out of range, maximum value is 4</ExceptionText>
  </Exception>
</ExceptionReport>
```

Why 4 and 9 are here?

As well for zoom = 0 it should be a whole planet on one tile, but not in NASA GIBS:

https://gibs.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts/epsg4326/best/MODIS_Terra_CorrectedReflectance_TrueColor/default/2016-09-03/250m/0/0/0.jpg :
[image: 0/0/0]

so you could ever ask row=0,col=1 tile:
[image: 0/0/1]

Why it is so strange and where am I wrong?

Comment: Did you look at the wmts standard?

Comment: Do you mean this one http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=35326 ? it is about 129 pages so I have just looked thought it and didn't find algorithm of projection in any form. Can you point where could I find correct algorithm for projection long, lat to row, col of tile?

Comment: Appendix b I think but if you are writing a wmts client you should read all of it

Comment: it has annexes only but no any appendixes. And Annex B about `XML Schema Documents`. Do you mean another wmts standard document? btw you could recommend any wmts clients in python which could work and fetch right tile or rectangle segment on long, lat and zoom. Because I don't really what to reinvent wheels but get any working python client to receive satellite images by long, lat

Comment: actually section 6.1 explains and Annex H has the pseudocode

Comment: do you mean that I should multiply tile span by factor?:

    pixelSpan = scaleDenominator × 0.28 10-3
/ metersPerUnit(crs);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've gotten [comment from Lucian  member of NASA team](https://github.com/nasa-gibs/onearth/issues/53#issuecomment-299738858)

> For GIBS GCS, the level 0 resolution is 288 deg / tile, not 180 deg/tile. It was chosen to approximate the full resolution of the MODIS images, avoiding oversampling or undersampling, while still having full width tiles at most levels (2 and up).
>
> Making this adjustment, the formula to use is:

```
row = ((90 + lat) * (2 ** level)) // 288
col = (180 + lon) * (2 ** level)) // 288
```

And it works!

Kia Ora cloudy New Zealand!

```
row = int((90˚ + 41˚) / 288˚ * 2 ^ 3) ≈ int(5,8222) = 3 
col = int((180˚ + 174˚) / 288˚ * 2 ^ 3) ≈ int(15.73333) = 9
```

https://gibs.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts/epsg4326/best/MODIS_Terra_CorrectedReflectance_TrueColor/default/2016-09-03/250m/3/3/9.jpg
[image: 3/3/9]